# what is root key for in mongodb configuration?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a config file that gets called in server.js for an express app, setting up a mongoDB database using mongoose. What is the `root` key? Why is it there?

```
var path = require('path')
var rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname + '../..')

/**
 * Expose config
 */

module.exports = {
  development: {
    root: rootPath,
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/your_app_db_dev'
  }
}
```

I've also seen `rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')`

In server.js the code is called with:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
  , config = require('./config/config')[env]

var db = mongoose.connect(config.db)

// bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport, config)

var app = express()

// express settings
require('./config/express')(app, config, passport)
```

Also, for bonus points, how does `__dirname` work? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"__dirname" is a predefined global variable in Node.js which gives the absolute path of the script file which is accessing __dirname.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

In this code "root" is a variable set to the absolute path of the root directory of your node.js project. This will work only if the config.js file is placed in a directory inside your root directory like this...

/your-node-project/config/config.js

Comment: Requests for bitcoin donations or other payment should not be included in answers. It *may* be OK to include in your user profile description (although I've not seen it done, and expect it may be frowned upon). The general reward for StackExchange is reputation/privileges and warm thanks from appreciative users ;-).